# How can I iterate over the children of a composite component to insert elements in between?

Tags: jsf

For example, I want to use the children inside a composite component `my:wrapperComponent` like this (pseudocode, not even sure if `ui:repeat` is appropriate):

```
...
<cc:implementation>
  <h:panelGrid columns="4">
      <ui:repeat value="#{somehow.get.to.the.children}" var="child">
         <h:outputText value="stuff here" />
         <my:otherStuffBetweenChildren />
         <ui:insertNext value="child"/>
         <h:outputText value="#{cc.more.stuff}" />
      </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGrid>
</cc:implementation>
```

then I want to use this wrapper component and fill it with a few children:

```
<my:wrapperComponent>
   <my:firstChild />
   <h:outputText value="second child" />
   <foo:thirdChildEtc />
</my:wrapperComponent>
```

Is this even possible with JSF? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I did some searching in stackoverflow but did not encounter any easy solution. The only thing I can think of (if you have a limited and fixed number of children with e.g. a specific 'role') is to use facets. These are named and can be placed anywhere in the output from the composite component based on their name. Compare with the header and footer facet in a datatable

Comment: @Kukeltje No, I want this specifically for a variable number of children! What really not possible?? What the.. :(

Comment: it is not easily possible in a composite component. There is an #{cc.children}, and you can iterate over them, but not 'move' them then... so the behaviour is not determined. Maybe a simple custom component in java with a render is more applicable in this case (and not difficult). But as usual, BalusC or some other real expert might know of a trick